# Does the Canon Connect Station work for image backup while traveling?

Tags: canon, travel, backup

I'm looking for a good way to backup SD cards while traveling without a computer. I know there are a number of options based on hard drives, but the one that seems most attractive right now is the [Canon Connect Station CS100](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/cameras/connect-station/connect-station-cs100). I'm having a hard time finding reliable reviews, though, and I'd like to know how well this device works for backup. It looks small enough to be portable and has a 1TB capacity, which is plenty for my needs, but the primary purpose seems to be to display images on a TV and perhaps to share them among devices. I don't see a lot of information about backup functionality. So...

- Does the CS100 save RAW images and allow the original images to be retrieved easily?
- Is it easy to connect to hotel wifi networks?
- How well (if at all) does the CS100 integrate with the Canon 6D
  built-in wifi?

Comment: It states clearly in the specifications on the page you linked to "Still Photos, JPEG, RAW (CR2 only)"  It has a card slot, why do  you want to (i would not)  use a WiFi connection if you are just using it to store files,  there is a card slot and a USB port. you can use the card slot with no worries about wireless screw-ups. It states clearly on the canon 6d page "Still images can even be transferred between two Wi-Fi enabled Canon cameras over a Local Area Network." I would assume since it is all canon products it is likely to be compatible. ( i know, assumptions,,,  Pffft.)

Comment: @Alaskaman I can see what formats the CS100 takes in, but it's not clear to me whether the original files are kept or if they're modified. The main purpose of the device seems to be to display photos on a TV and perhaps share them with other CS100's. It does say that it accepts CR2 files, but also that it only displays the JPEG preview image and doesn't process the raw file itself, so it's not obvious that it even keeps the raw image. As for the SD slot, you could make the same argument about NFC, but the device still supports it. Same goes for wifi. These aren't unreasonable questions.

Answer (score 1):

the CS100 doesn't work well with RAW, it only displays it on your monitor, but won't let you share it back on the Canon Image Gateway.

Answer (score -1):

Of course the *main* function of the product is image backup.  Right in the Features category of the product it is stated:

> **Up to 1 TB of Storage**
>
> Canon Connect Station CS100 is a practical long-term solution to your image storage needs.

I do not agree that *"the primary purpose seems to be to display images on a TV and perhaps to share them among devices"*. Sure the display of images is a feature, maybe a strong secondary function but the main purpose is the storage of images.

Yes it saves images. You can retrieve them via the USB (2.0) port later.

I think you can find other better options.  Canon tried to build something here that isn't really needed in my opinion.

Here's a review with more info - http://petapixel.com/2015/12/01/review-canons-cs100-connect-station-is-overpriced-and-unnecessary/

Comment: Didn't like my answer? What was not useful about it?